# PostgreSQL ERROR: operator does not exist: enum12 = integer

Tags: java, postgresql, jdbc

Getting an operator mismatch error when doing a simple query. What causes this?

I am using JDBC `preStmt.setInt(1, Integer.parseInt(user));`

```
 dev_db=# \d+ registrants
                                  Table "public.registrants"
        Column    |           Type           |     Modifiers      | Storage  | Description
    --------------+--------------------------+--------------------+----------+-------------
     user         | enum12                   | not null           | plain    |
     degree       | text                     |                    | extended |
```

Comment: What is the definition of `enum12`?

Comment: I have defined 1 is guest user and 2 is admin

Comment: Why are you using an enum to limit allowed values for a number? That doesn't make sense. Use a proper lookup table with a foreign key or a check constraint. An enum is the wrong choice for this.

Answer (score 0):

I'll assume that `enum12` was created with `CREATE TYPE enum12 AS ENUM (...)`.

The problem is that you cannot automatically cast integers to an enumerated data type (but it works for strings).

If you *really* need to be able to cast integers to `enum12`, you could use the following:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION int_to_enum12(integer) RETURNS enum12
   LANGUAGE sql IMMUTABLE STRICT AS
   $$SELECT enumlabel::enum12
     FROM pg_catalog.pg_enum
     WHERE enumsortorder = $1
       AND enumtypid = 'enum12'::regtype$$;

CREATE CAST (integer AS enum12)
   WITH FUNCTION int_to_enum12(integer)
   AS IMPLICIT;
```

Then your example will probably work.

**Notes:**

- This assumes that the first label corresponds to '1'.
- Integers out of range will be cast to `NULL`.
- Adding implicit casts to your database will increase the ambiguity of your SQL statements, leading to more errors like:

  ```
  ERROR: operator is not unique: ...
  HINT: Could not choose a best candidate operator. You might need to add explicit type casts.
  ```

I think you might be better off rephrasing the query so that you don't need a type cast.

Comment: I think he might actually be better of not (ab)using enums for this.